# Python and Excel - OpenPyXL

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, openpyxl

I am working with Excel using Python and have couple of questions:

1. Loading Excel Sheet into 2d Array.
   In VBA I'd simply do:

```
dim arrData as Variant 
arrData = shtData.Range("A1:E2500")
```

I would get array(1 to 2500, 1 to 5), which i can easily access for example arrData(1,5) -> row 1 column 5

In Python what i managed to do is:

```
#declare list
excel_data=[]

#loop to load excel spreadsheet data into 2d Array   
#basically I am looping through every row and append it to list
for row in shtData.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=50,values_only =True):
    excel_data.append(row)
```

2. Is there a way to assign row to list, starting from index 1 not 0? 
   In VBA there is an option Option Base 1. 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement
3. Is it the fastest way to operate on Excel Dataset? 
   I am planning then to loop through let's say 2500 rows and 5 columns -> 12'500 cells. 
   With VBA it was very efficient to be honest (operating on array in memory).
4. As I understand, functionsof OpenPyXL:

```
load_workbook
```

#only creates REFERENCE TO EXCEL WORKBOOK - it does not open it? or is it "loaded" into memory but what is on the HD is actually intact?

```
shtData = wkb.worksheets[0]
```

#again only reference?

```
shtReport = wkb.create_sheet(title="ReportTable")
```

#it adds sheet but it adds it in excel which is loaded into memory, only after saving, Excel on HD is actually overwritten?

Answer (score 2):

You can used Pandas and create a dataframe (2D table) from the Excel spreadsheat.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("data.xls")
print(df)
print("____________")
print(f'Average sales are: {df["Gross"].values.mean()}')
print(f'Net income for April: {df.at[3, "Net"]}')
print("____________")
df_no_header = pd.read_excel("data.xls",skiprows=1, header=None)
print(df_no_header)
print("____________")
print(f'Net income for April: {df_no_header.at[3, 2]}')
```

Output:

[image: output]

The Pandas dataframe has many methods that will allow you to access rows and columns and do much more.  Setting skiprows=1, header=None will skip the header row. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html).

Comment: Is it possible then to manipulate Excel with that? Or do I still need OpenPyXL?

Comment: You don't need OpenPyXL at all.  This is a much more powerful alternative.  If you routinely deal with importing large amount of data from Excel, get comfortable with Pandas.